# Is there a function to find text files in a directory?

Tags: c, path, directory

Is there a function that can find all the `.txt` files in a special directory that I enter it but can't find in its subdirectory?

Comment: `dir \yourdir\*.txt` in Windows, `ls /yourdir/*.txt` in Linux?

Comment: What is the significance of the 'cannot find in its subdirectory' condition?  Also, what is special about the directory (or did you mean 'specific')?  You should explain more clearly and fully what you are after, possibly including a small example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`glob(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob)

Comment: @amin: what do you mean by 'structural'?  Does it use a structure?  Yes. (Did you follow the link to take a look?)